# How to crop a zoomable and draggable images in a picturebox

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I am looking for some help regarding the picturebox controls in vb.net. I have a form which displays an image. I did not choose a normal picture box to display the image. Instead I chose an user control where I can load the image and do functionality like zoom in, zoom out, drag the image to a new location inside the user control..

I now have to crop a portion of the image and save it in the computer as JPEG. But the problem I face is when I crop the image I dont get to see the exact selected part of the image, instead some other portion of the image gets saved. Is there a solution where I can actually zoom in, move an image and crop it or the cropping functionality works only with images that cannot be dragged or zoomed? Please provide your suggesions..Thanks in advance!!

Comment: very broad since we dont know what this UserControl is comprised of.  This should be able to be done with a picbox on a panel using autoscroll, and some code to do the zoom and cropping.

Comment: I was able to achieve the zoom and pan effects. Lets say an image is fit inside a picturebox. When i crop this image, I get a perfect portion of the image that is cropped. Now I move the image to another point in the picure box by dragging it...When i try to crop the image now, I dont get the cropped portion of the image now.. Instead I get the portion of image  which i would have when the image was in its original location..Do you get my point here...?!

Comment: when you move/pan to another location the current viewport (and subsequent rectangle you want to copy/crop) is going to be relative to that offset.  The reason I mentioned the picbox on a panel is that it will provide that offset for you.  If you provided your own code pan/move code, you need to track that offset yourself.

Comment: Ok I will look into the offset calculation. I have a rectangle selection which can be used to select a portion of the image for cropping..Since I have set Autoscroll property = True, I get scroll bars..But if I have to do selection beyond my current window, I cannot do so when the mouse reaches the extreme right of the picturebox.. I would like to design it in a way that when mouse reaches the extreme right my scroll bars should automatically move right.. But with Autosroll property I cannot get the scrollbar values. Any workaround available for this problem??